# Estilizar v-data-table

Tags: html, css, vue.js, vuetify

¿Cómo puedo estilizar una v-data-table (vuetify) de la siguiente manera?

[image: EJEMPLO]

Es decir, cada item de la tabla este dividida por cards

Comment: ¿Y qué has intentado?